# How to test persistent actors with ScalaTest, ZIO and Akka

Tags: scala, akka, scalatest, akka-persistence, zio

I have one "use case" that I would like to test. This one returns a `zio.IO` resulting from a call to an Actor (`scala.concurrent.Future`). And, I would like to use ScalaTest's `AnyWordSpec`.

```scala
  val actorRef = testKit.spawn(/* Real behavior */)

  "AkkaZioAndScalatest" should {

    "collaborate to write readable tests" in {
      val subject = new UseCaseWithAkkaAndZio(actorRef)
      val result =  zio.Runtime.default.unsafeRun(for {
        _ <- subject.apply("Hello")
        msg <- actorRef.askIO(GetMessage(_))
      } yield {
        msg
      })

      result should be ("Hello")
    }
  }
```

```scala
class UseCaseWithAkkaAndZio(actorRef: ActorRef) {
  def apply(msg:String):UIO[Unit] = {
    // askIO is an implicit method that `ask` and convert the Future to UIO
    actorRef.askIO(SetMessage(msg))
  }
}
```

I have turned around this test for a while without being able to have something working.

At this time, with the code sample above, I get this error:

> [info]   zio.FiberFailure: Fiber failed.
> [info] An unchecked error was produced.
> [info] java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Recipient[Actor[akka://UseCaseWithAkkaAndZioTest/user/$a#2047466881]] had already been terminated.
> [info]    at akka.actor.typed.scaladsl.AskPattern$PromiseRef.(AskPattern.scala:140) 
> [info] ...

Can someone help with this idea? I have to admit that I feel a bit lost here.

Thanks

---

**EDIT** To be complete, and as suggested by @Gaston here is the reproducible example.

Please note that it works when using a `Behavior` but fails when using a `EventSourcedBehavior`. (Thanks Gaston, I have discovered that when writing the example).

```scala
package org

import akka.actor.typed.ActorRef
import akka.cluster.sharding.typed.scaladsl.EntityRef
import akka.util.Timeout
import zio._

import scala.concurrent.duration.DurationInt

package object example {

  implicit final class EntityRefOps[-M](actorRef: EntityRef[M]) {

    private val timeout: Timeout = Timeout(5.seconds)

    def askIO[E, A](p: ActorRef[Either[E, A]] => M): ZIO[Any, E, A] = {
      IO.fromFuture(_ => actorRef.ask(p)(timeout))
        .orDie
        .flatMap(e => IO.fromEither(e))
    }

  }

}
```

```scala
package org.example

import akka.actor.typed.scaladsl.Behaviors
import akka.actor.typed.{ActorRef, Behavior, SupervisorStrategy}
import akka.cluster.sharding.typed.scaladsl.EntityTypeKey
import akka.persistence.typed.PersistenceId
import akka.persistence.typed.scaladsl.{Effect, EventSourcedBehavior, RetentionCriteria}

import scala.concurrent.duration.DurationInt

object GreeterPersistentActor {

  sealed trait Command
  case class SetMessage(message: String, replyTo: ActorRef[Either[Throwable, Unit]]) extends Command
  case class GetMessage(replyTo: ActorRef[Either[Throwable, String]]) extends Command

  val TypeKey: EntityTypeKey[Command] = EntityTypeKey[Command](getClass.getSimpleName)

  type ReplyEffect = akka.persistence.typed.scaladsl.ReplyEffect[Event, State]

  trait Event
  case class MessageSet(message: String) extends Event

  case class State(message: Option[String]) {
    def handle(cmd:Command):ReplyEffect = cmd match {
      case c: SetMessage =>
        val event = MessageSet(c.message)
        Effect.persist(event).thenReply(c.replyTo)(_ => Right(():Unit))
      case c: GetMessage =>
        message match {
          case Some(value) =>
            Effect.reply(c.replyTo)(Right(value))
          case None =>
            Effect.reply(c.replyTo)(Left(new Exception("No message set")))
        }
    }

    def apply(evt:Event):State = evt match {
      case e:MessageSet => State(Some(e.message))
    }
  }

  def apply(persistenceId: PersistenceId, message: Option[String]): Behavior[Command] = EventSourcedBehavior
    .withEnforcedReplies[Command, Event, State](
      persistenceId,
      State(message),
      (state, cmd) => state.handle(cmd),
      (state, evt) => state.apply(evt)
    )
    .withTagger(_ => Set("Sample"))
    .withRetention(
      RetentionCriteria.snapshotEvery(100, 2)
    )
    .onPersistFailure(
      SupervisorStrategy.restartWithBackoff(200.millis, 5.seconds, 0.2d)
    )

}
```

```scala
package org.example

import akka.cluster.sharding.typed.scaladsl.EntityRef
import zio._

class UseCaseWithAkkaAndZio(entityRefFor: String=>EntityRef[GreeterPersistentActor.Command]) {
  def apply(entityId: String, msg: String): IO[Throwable, Unit] = {
    entityRefFor(entityId).askIO(GreeterPersistentActor.SetMessage(msg, _))
  }
}
```

```scala
package org.example

import akka.actor.testkit.typed.scaladsl.ScalaTestWithActorTestKit
import akka.cluster.sharding.typed.scaladsl.{EntityRef, EntityTypeKey}
import akka.cluster.sharding.typed.testkit.scaladsl.TestEntityRef
import akka.persistence.typed.PersistenceId
import org.scalatest.wordspec.AnyWordSpecLike

class UseCaseWithAkkaAndZioSpec extends ScalaTestWithActorTestKit with AnyWordSpecLike {


  "AkkaZioAndScalatest" should {
    "collaborate to write readable tests" in {
      val entityId = "Sample"
      val actorRef = testKit.spawn(GreeterPersistentActor.apply(PersistenceId("Sample", entityId), None))
      val entityRefFor:String=>EntityRef[GreeterPersistentActor.Command] = TestEntityRef(
        EntityTypeKey[GreeterPersistentActor.Command]("Greeter"),
        _,
        actorRef
      )
      val subject = new UseCaseWithAkkaAndZio(entityRefFor)
      val result = zio.Runtime.default.unsafeRun(for {
        _ <- subject.apply(entityId, "Hello")
        msg <- entityRefFor(entityId).askIO(GreeterPersistentActor.GetMessage(_))
      } yield {
        println(s"Answer is $msg")
        msg
      })

      result should be("Hello")
    }
  }

}
```

```scala
// build.sbt
ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.13.11"

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "sample",
    libraryDependencies +=  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor-typed" % "2.8.2",
    libraryDependencies +=  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-persistence-typed" % "2.8.2",
    libraryDependencies +=  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-cluster-sharding-typed" % "2.8.2",
    libraryDependencies +=  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor-testkit-typed" % "2.8.2" % Test,
    libraryDependencies +=  "dev.zio" %% "zio" % "1.0.18",
    libraryDependencies +=  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.2.16" % Test,
  )
```

Comment: An ask will fail-fast if the target of the ask is known to have stopped.  It looks like the actor you're spawning is shared between tests, so is it possible that another test stops/crashes the actor?

Comment: could you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @LeviRamsey At this time, there is only one test (see the reproducible example in my edit).

Comment: If I'm not wrong, you are using the [testkit for actors](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/testing.html) instead of the [testkit for persistent actors](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/persistence-testing.html). Also looks like you are using akka cluster sharding. In the [integration test for akka persistence](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/persistence-testing.html) give details about that.

Comment: You are not wrong. I have found the "solution" and edited my question again.

Comment: No worries. That's part of the learning path. Feel happy that now you know how to do it.

Comment: With your last edit, you added a new question which is not related to the issue you had at the beginning. We should have one [question per post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275908/more-than-one-question-per-post). Also the [question has the answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387723/answer-a-question-inside-the-question) and the post stills without a correct answer. Could you edit it and move your new question to a new post, remove the solution and post it as an answer to be marked as the correct one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a testkit for [testing persistent actors](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/persistence-testing.html).

`EventSourcedBehaviorTestKit` must be mixed into the suite test

```scala
class UseCaseWithAkkaAndZioSpec extends ScalaTestWithActorTestKit(EventSourcedBehaviorTestKit.config) with AnyWordSpecLike {
  // the tests
}
```

**EDIT:**

Another question that was part of the original one was to remove the `zio.Runtime.unsafeRun`.

My actual solution is to create a few `Matcher[ZIO[...]` that allows me to write test like :

```
  val effect:IO[Throwable, String] = ???
  effect should completeMatching {
    case str:String => // Yes. This is useless, but for the example
  }

trait ZioMatchers {

  def completeMatching(matcher: PartialFunction[Any, Any]): Matcher[IO[Any, Any]] = (effect: IO[Any, Any]) => {
    val (complete, matches, result) = zio.Runtime.default
      .unsafeRun(
        effect
          .flatMap {
            case res if matcher.isDefinedAt(res) => ZIO.succeed((true, true, res))
            case other                           => ZIO.succeed(true, false, other)
          }
          .catchAll(err => ZIO.succeed(false, false, err))
      )
      ...
  }

  ...
}
```